# Отправка изображения графика из Google Таблиц в Telegram через бота

Tags: telegram-bot, google-apps-script

Я пытаюсь отправлять изображение графика в telegram. Для этого я получил ссылку на него в Google Таблицах (`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT2m7WvYiTxSJ8uXGmnSSoYC4UrakMRlycj2JtDcSc34gpz1QixZwNSsW0MCgbm6PHnYSPoBRjUzYgp/pubchart?oid=182564157&format=image`)
Выглядит это так (и обновляется по мере обновления данных в таблице):
[image]

Далее я отправляю запрос в telegram следующего вида:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch(encodeURI("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botApi +"/sendPhoto?chat_id=" + channel + "&photo=" + "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT2m7WvYiTxSJ8uXGmnSSoYC4UrakMRlycj2JtDcSc34gpz1QixZwNSsW0MCgbm6PHnYSPoBRjUzYgp/pubchart?oid=182564157&format=image" + "&caption=" + "График" + "&parse_mode=html"));
```

На что получаю следующий ответ:
[image: Bad Request: failed to get HTTP URL content]

Телеграму чем-то не нравится именно эта ссылка, так как если "скормить" ему какую-нибудь ссылку с `.png` на конце, то он успешно отправляет это изображение, а здесь почему-то не хочет.

Подскажите, как можно побороть эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

[Google Apps Script Library для работы с API Telegram.](https://github.com/Guf-Hub/TGBot)

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Название листа");
// пример, отправка графика (фото .png) с листа Google Sheets
const blob = sheet.getCharts()[0].getBlob();

Bot.sendPhoto({
  chat_id: chat_id,
  photo: blob,
  contentType: "multipart/form-data" // указать обязательно
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что это не картинка.

Попробуйте отправить Blob

```js
function getChartImage_() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.openById('bookId')
    .getSheetByName('sheetName')
    .getCharts()
    [0].getBlob();
}
```

```js
const photo = getChartImage_();
sendPhoto(chatId, photo);
```

Где

```js
  sendPhoto(chatId, photo, caption) {
    return getResponse('sendPhoto', {
      chat_id: '' + chatId,
      photo: photo,
      caption: caption || '',
    }).getContentText();
  }
```

```js
  getResponse(method, data) {
    const httpResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
     'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/' + method,
    {
      method: 'post',
      payload: data,
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    });

    return httpResponse;
  }
```